# Translated title of collection does not show (using biblatex-chicago)

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

As an East Asianist, I often need to have a book title in three versions: a latinized version, the original title, and a translation. 
For a "book" entry, I am using the biblatex-chicago fields `title`, `titleaddon`, and `usere` for those three purposes, following suggestions in this stackexchange.

Now what I want to do is to have the same three versions of a title showing up for parts of a collection - that is, not only for the article itself, but also for the collection that is referred to in the reference.

Is there any way to do this (other than writing multiple versions of the title into the same field)?

I tried the following mwe:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Han Sans}
\usepackage[ notes,
    backend=biber,
]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mwe_bibliography.bib}
@incollection{Farrer1965Christian,
  author   = {Farrer, Austin},
  title    = {The Christian Apologist},
  crossref = {Gibb1965Light},
}
@collection{Gibb1965Light,
  editor   = {Gibb, Jocelyn},
  title    = {Light on C.S. Lewis},
  titleaddon = {中文書名},
  usere = {titel in translation},
  publisher= {Harcourt, Brace \& World},
  address  = {New York, NY}, 
  year     = {1965},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{mwe_bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
    \autocite{Farrer1965Christian}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It does not quite work the way I want it to; "title in translation" now shows up as part of the entry, not of the collection itself:

[image: reference]

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you tell us what style you use? A full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) would tell us not only that, but would also give us a good way to start our investigations immediately without having to guess and come up with a document ourselves. You can increase your chances of getting a good answer quickly by editing your post to add an MWE.

Comment: Do you use the `authordate` or `note` style? Please consider adding an MWE.

Comment: Sorry for not including an MWE in my original post! I hope this one is fine. I am using the "notes" style.